# Is there a way to suggest label names in org-mode html export?

Tags: org-mode, html

In the org-mode example below, I would like to be able to specify the label name to be used by the latex export back-end. Is there such a way?

I have a reason : To be able to mix org-style references `[[fig:label]]` and latex-style references `\ref{fig:label}` in the same document. This is not necessary (in fact, probably bad practice) if I have everything in the org document.

example :

### in org file

```
#+NAME: eq:001
#+label: eq:001
\begin{equation}\begin{split}
x_c(t)=p(t)x(t)
\end{split}\end{equation}

in cui

#+NAME: eq:1012
#+label: eq:1012
\begin{equation}\begin{split}
p(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t - nT_c)
\end{split}\end{equation}


per cui la [[eq:001]] diventa
```

but when export in html i get

### html file

```
\begin{equation}\begin{split}
\label{eq:001}
x_c(t)=p(t)x(t)
\end{split}\end{equation}

<p>
in cui
</p>

\begin{equation}\begin{split}
\label{eq:1012}
p(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t - nT_c)
\end{split}\end{equation}


<p>
per cui la \eqref{eq:001} diventa
</p>
```

but in browser program i get

```
per cui (???)
```

I don't understand why.